# Getting incorrect output when trying to use generics in python3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, python-typing

Here is the code I have:

```
from typing import (
    TypeVar,
    Iterable,
    Generic,
    Callable,
    Deque,
    Any,
    Optional,
    Protocol,
    Sequence,
)
from heapq import heappush, heappop

T = TypeVar("T")


def linear_contains(iterable: Iterable[T], key: T) -> bool:
    for item in iterable:
        if item == key:
            return True
        return False


C = TypeVar("C", bound="Comparable")


class Comparable(Protocol):
    def __eq__(self, other: Any) -> bool:
        ...

    def __lt__(self: C, other: C) -> bool:
        ...

    def __gt__(self: C, other: C) -> bool:
        return (not self < other) and self != other

    def __le__(self: C, other: C) -> bool:
        return self < other and self == other

    def __ge__(self: C, other: C) -> bool:
        return not self < other


def binary_contains(sequence: Sequence[C], key: C) -> bool:
    low: int = 0
    high: int = len(sequence) - 1
    while low < high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if sequence[mid] < key:
            low = mid + 1
        elif sequence[mid] > key:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            return True
    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(linear_contains([1, 4, 5, 23, 23, 23, 30], 5))
    print(binary_contains(["a", "d", "e", "f", "x", "z"], "f"))
    print(binary_contains(["john", "maek", "ronald", "sarah"], "sheila"))
```

The expected output is

```
True
True
False
```

But I am getting

```
False
False
False
```

Can someone explain why that is happening?

PS: This code is take from the book Classic CS Problems in Python ([here](https://github.com/davecom/ClassicComputerScienceProblemsInPython/blob/master/Chapter2/generic_search.py)). It was written for python3.7, but I want to make it run in python 3.10. I am aware that there have been a lot of changes with `typing` in python, but I have been having some problem with understanding it well (especially generics). That's why started with this code.

Comment: You are asking about unexpected runtime results, but you talk about typing. Those two rarely have anything to do with one another in Python. And in this case, they don't. You just have bugs in your implementations. Which is strange since you cite the source that does not have those bugs.

Comment: So if I am getting an output, does that suggest that there is no typing related issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with typing. Here is the code for the two functions **copied and pasted directly** from the [link](https://github.com/davecom/ClassicComputerScienceProblemsInPython/blob/master/Chapter2/generic_search.py) you provided.

Can you spot the difference between this version and the version you used? Feel free to ask follow up questions if any in the comments.

```py
def linear_contains(iterable: Iterable[T], key: T) -> bool:
    for item in iterable:
        if item == key:
            return True
    return False
```

```py
def binary_contains(sequence: Sequence[C], key: C) -> bool:
    low: int = 0
    high: int = len(sequence) - 1
    while low <= high:  # while there is still a search space
        mid: int = (low + high) // 2
        if sequence[mid] < key:
            low = mid + 1
        elif sequence[mid] > key:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            return True
    return False
```